# How to Validate special characters in a textbox and show entered special characters in the error message?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

There is a textbox and a button that validates the entry inside the textbox.
That if it should not validate the presence of illegal characters in the form.
Suppose I entered the following word "Lorem# %ipsum^"

On clicking the button, two things should happen

- If there sre any special chars like #$%^&, then the form submission should fail.
- An error message should pop up like  "You have used the illegal characters #, % and ^ in your form"

What is the best method?
P.S: I would like a solution not involving jquery.

Comment: Is that really the requirement? Wouldn't it be more sensible to have a message such as 'only letters, digits, underscore and hyphen are allowed'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var invalidChars = str.match(/[^\w ]/g), output = '';
if (invalidChars) {
    invalidChars = invalidChars.unique();
    var lastInvalidChar = invalidChars.pop();
    output = 'You have used the illegal character' + (invalidChars.length > 0 ? 's' : '') + ' ' +
        invalidChars.join(', ') + (invalidChars.length > 0 ? ' and ' : '') + lastInvalidChar;
}
```

Here `match` and the regular expression `/[^\w ]/g` is used to get all characters that are neither word characters nor a space. The array of matched invalid characters is then cleaned from duplicates using the custom `unique` method (see below). Then the last invalid character is removed from the array to append it if necessary with an “and” at the end of the output. The remaining invalid characters (if there are any) are then joined with commas and combined with the last invalid character.

Since JavaScript has no built-in `unique` method to remove duplicates, you can use this method:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var index = {};
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; ++i) {
        if (!index.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
            index[this[i]] = this[i];
        }
    }
    var clean = [];
    for (var prop in index) {
        if (index.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            clean.push(index[prop]);
        }
    }
    return clean;
};
```

Note that this implementation is not type-safe as the values are used as property names and thus turned into strings. So `["3",3].unique()` returns `["3"]` hence `"3".toString() === (3).toString()`.

Comment: what has javascript come to.. :P

Comment: @Gumbo: What I would like is a javascript solution, without php

Comment: @naveen: Sorry, somehow I had PHP in mind when writing the answer. I’ve updated it with a JavaScript implementation (basically the same).

Comment: @Gumbo: Great Answer. I found a small bug with it though. So i am altering the first four lines var invalidChars = str.match(/[^\w ]/g);var output = '';
if (invalidChars) {
     invalidChars = invalidChars.unique();
    var lastInvalidChar = invalidChars.pop();.. because if str.match is null then unioque function cannot be called. is my method correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
var myString = document.getElementById("myInputField").value; // gets the sentence
var invalidChars = myString.replace(/[^#%\^]*/g, ""); //gets the chars | "#%^" in your case
var response = "";

for(var  i = 0; i < invalidChars.length; i+){
  response += (i > 0? (i == invalidChars-1 ? " and ": ", "):"") + invalidChars[i];
}

if (response != "") {
  alert("Your data contains invalid characters " + response);
}
```

For more info on js regexes check out

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html