# How to show Error Message when special character and submit button is pressed without entering any value in text-box?

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {
if (!empty($_POST['txt'])){
$veggies = array("Potato", "Cucumber", "Carrot", "Orange", "Green Beans", "onion");
$fruits  = array("Apple", "Banana", "orange", "Pineapple", "Grapes", "Watermelon");
$salad   = array_merge ($veggies, $fruits);
$Object = $_POST['txt'];
$search = array_filter($salad, function($list) use ($Object) {
    return ( stripos($list, $Object) !== FALSE );
});
 print_r($search);

} 

 else {  
    echo 'Enter Item'; 

 }

}

?>
<form method="POST">
Search item:  <input type="text" name="txt" ><br> <br>
      <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

How to show error message when special characters are entered like (@,/. etc), only letters should be allowed. I'm trying from few days but unable to fix the problem.can any one guide me in solving this issue ?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554043/how-to-validate-special-characters-in-a-textbox-and-show-entered-special-charact?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Validate special characters in a textbox and show entered special characters in the error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554043/how-to-validate-special-characters-in-a-textbox-and-show-entered-special-charact)

Comment: i'm doing this in php so i need to guidence in php only.

Comment: can't it be done in php?

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>

            <?php

            if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {
            if (!empty($_POST['txt'])){
            $veggies = array("Potato", "Cucumber", "Carrot", "Orange", "Green Beans", "onion");
            $fruits  = array("Apple", "Banana", "orange", "Pineapple", "Grapes", "Watermelon");
            $salad   = array_merge ($veggies, $fruits);
            $Object = $_POST['txt'];
            $search = array_filter($salad, function($list) use ($Object) {
                return ( stripos($list, $Object) !== FALSE );
            });
             print_r($search);

            } 

             else {  
                echo 'Enter Item'; 

             }

            }

            ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function validateInput(e){
        var key;
       document.all ? key = e.keyCode : key = e.which;
   if ((key > 64 && key< 91) || (key > 96 && key< 123) || key == 8 ||key == 32) {
            alert("Invalid input");

           }
    }

    function validateForm() {
           var value = $("#submitbtn").val();
           if(value == NULL) {
             alert("Please enter input value");
             return false;
           }

    }
            </script>
            <form method="POST">
            Search item:  <input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="return validateInput(event)"/><br> <br>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submitbtn" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
            </form>

            </body>
            </html>
```